# Slickgrid: Using an object's member as a column field?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have an object which has two members:
`num` which is just an integer and `article` which is an object that I get through JSON and has a number of members itself. Now I want to use members from article for the `name` and `pris` fields in a SlickGrid. The example beneath does not seem to work however:

```
var columns = [
    { id: "antal", name: "Antal", field: "num", width:  10},
        { id: "namn", name: "Artikelnamn", field: "article.name", width: 50},
        { id: "pris", name: "Totalpris", field: "article.price", width: 50}
];
```

Can anyone assist me in implementing this correctly based on the code provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `article` as the field, and employ a column formatter.  So:

```
var columns = [
    { 
        id: "antal", name: "Antal", field: "num", width:  10
    },
    { 
        id: "namn", name: "Artikelnamn", field: "article", width: 50, 
        formatter : function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
            return value.name;
        }
     },
    { 
        id: "pris", name: "Totalpris", field: "article", width: 50,
        formatter : function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
            return value.price;
        }

    }
];
```